# JSON sending class A goes in class B

Tags: java, web-services, json

I am starting out on Restful web services and learning through JSON google gson. Though till now i have just made my server producer and json consumer application.
and i am loving it.

Now this is my consumer code: it has a TextMessages class object message

```
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
InputStreamReader reader = null;
String name = nameTextfield.getText();
String url = "http://myurl/" + name;
    try {
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StartClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StartClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    TextMessages message = new Gson().fromJson(reader, TextMessages.class);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message.getMessage(), "Welcome" + message.sumAllIntegers(), 
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}
```

// class TextMessages

```
package use;

public class TextMessages{
private String message;
private int a,b,c,d,wee;

public TextMessages(String __message){
    message = __message;        
}
public TextMessages(){
}

public String getMessage(){
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String __message){
    message = __message;
}
```

}

Now server is sending JSON of class OtherTestMessage

```
public class TextMessage {
    private String message;
    //getter and setter functions
    // no int a,b
.....
```

Why is it working right ? Shoule it be working right ? is it again languages philosophy? how does JSON convert things. Or is it donot ?  Just copying data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gson library is looking at the JSON and mapping what it can to the class you provide.

Both of your classes have a `String` called `message` in them. gson is taking the `message` element in the JSON and storing the value in both cases. In your `TextMessages` class, it will also store the values for `a`, `b`, etc if those elements are present in the JSON.

In the case of your `TextMessage` class that only has `String message`, the additional elements in the JSON (`a`,`b`, etc) are silently ignored if they are present.